# How can I write "echo" command in playbook (yaml)

Tags: ansible

I want to know how I can write the equivalent of the following command in an ansible playbook.

```sh
echo \
  "deb [arch=arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

Comment: What have you tried? What error message are you seeing?

Comment: You basically don't use shell commands in ansible when you have a dedicated module that can do the job idem-potently for you. See the [`apt_repository` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_repository_module.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check out `>` and `|` fold [operators](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics):

```
  - name: Print a message
    shell: >
      echo   "deb [arch=arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" |
      tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list  > /dev/null
    register: results
```

Here is the o/p of the the content in the file:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list 
deb [arch=arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu  bionic stable
```